# VS Code Chrome Debug React App

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have chrome debugger installed in vscode. I'm not sure how to debug my react app(server rendered).

Here is the app structure in browser source tab:

> localhost > public > js > src(Actual Application code)

Here is the physical app structure. Also, I am using gulp to bundle my app:

> root > dist > js > (bundle.js, bundle.map.js, lib.js, lib.map.js)

Here is my launch configuration:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://local.dporganizer.com/",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--user-data-dir",
            "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
        ],
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/public/js/src"
    }]
}
```

When I start the debugger and attach a breakpoint, I am getting this alert

> breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)